# Assign var from element of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a slider I built using a known slide width, but I need to change it to accomodate different sized slides of unknown widths.

**The Problem**
I am setting an array with the widths of each slide inside my container. When you click the next and back buttons it needs to pull in the width from the array of the corresponding element and slide the parent container to the left that amount. Right now it is only sliding a set amount since the var does not update with the new width (amount to slide).

Here is a jsFiddle. On click of next or prev, the content should slide so that the title is positions where it is innitially.
http://jsfiddle.net/qKpWb/3/

Here is my code:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var insuranceSlideSpeed = 600;
    var slideResetSpeed = 1800;
    var insuranceTotalSlides = $('.insurance-slide-controller').children().length;
    var insuranceCurrentSlide = 1;
    var insuranceNextSlide = 1;
    var insuranceSlideArray = [];
    var insuranceSlideWidthArray = [];
    var currentSlideWidth = 0;
    var totalSlidesWidth = 0;
    var currentSlideWidthTotal = 0;
    var insuranceSlide = 0;

    $('#insuranceSlideController').children().each(function() {
        //add individual class for each item
        var insuranceSlideClass = ('.insuranceItem' + insuranceSlide);
        $(this).addClass(insuranceSlideClass);
        //get width of current and total items
        currentSlideWidth = $(this).width();
        currentSlideWidthTotal = currentSlideWidth + 70;
        totalSlidesWidth = totalSlidesWidth + currentSlideWidth;
        //assign each item to array
        insuranceSlideArray.push(insuranceSlideClass);
        insuranceSlideWidthArray.push(currentSlideWidth);
        //console.log("insuranceSlideClass = " + insuranceSlideClass);
        //console.log("insuranceSlide = " + insuranceSlide);
        insuranceSlide ++;
    });
    //console.log("insuranceSlideArray = " + insuranceSlideArray);
    //console.log("insuranceSlideWidthArray = " + insuranceSlideWidthArray);

    $('.insurance-slider-next').click(function(){
        insuranceNextSlide ++;
        if (insuranceCurrentSlide < insuranceTotalSlides) {
            $('.insurance-slide-controller').animate({ 'left': '-=' + currentSlideWidthTotal + 'px' }, insuranceSlideSpeed );
            insuranceCurrentSlide = insuranceNextSlide;
        } else {
            resetInsuranceSlider();
            insuranceNextSlide = insuranceCurrentSlide;
        }
    });

    $('.insurance-slider-prev').click(function(){
        insuranceNextSlide --;
        if (insuranceCurrentSlide > 1) {
            $('.insurance-slide-controller').animate({ 'left': '+=' + currentSlideWidthTotal + 'px' }, insuranceSlideSpeed );
            insuranceCurrentSlide = insuranceNextSlide;
        } else {
            insuranceNextSlide = insuranceCurrentSlide;
        }
    });

    function resetInsuranceSlider(){
        $('.insurance-slide-controller').animate({ 'left': '70' }, slideResetSpeed );
        insuranceCurrentSlide = 1;
        insuranceNextSlide = 1;
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<!-- Slider -->
<div class="insurance-description-slider">
    <div class="insurance-slider-next">next</div>
    <div class="insurance-slider-prev">previous</div>
    <div class="insurance-slider-content">
        <div class="insurance-slide-controller" id="insuranceSlideController">
            <!-- Slide Section -->
            <div class="insurance-slide">
                <div class="insurance-slide-divider"></div>
                <div class="insurance-slide-label">title1</div>
                <!-- Slide Item -->
                <div class="insurance-slide-item">
                    <div class="insurance-item-headline">header</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-copy">Copy copy copy copy copy copy copy</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-link"><a href="#">link</a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- END Slide Item -->
            </div>
            <!-- END Slide Section -->
            <!-- Slide Section -->
            <div class="insurance-slide">
                <div class="insurance-slide-divider"></div>
                <div class="insurance-slide-label">title2</div>
                <!-- Slide Item -->
                <div class="insurance-slide-item">
                    <div class="insurance-item-headline">header</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-copy">Copy copy copy copy copy copy copy</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-link"><a href="#">link</a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- END Slide Item -->
                <div class="insurance-slide-item">
                    <div class="insurance-item-headline">header</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-copy">Copy copy copy copy copy copy copy</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-link"><a href="#">link</a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- END Slide Item -->
            </div>
            <!-- END Slide Section -->
            <!-- Slide Section -->
            <div class="insurance-slide">
                <div class="insurance-slide-divider"></div>
                <div class="insurance-slide-label">title3</div>
                <!-- Slide Item -->
                <div class="insurance-slide-item">
                    <div class="insurance-item-headline">header</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-copy">Copy copy copy copy copy copy copy</div>
                    <div class="insurance-item-link"><a href="#">link</a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- END Slide Item -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END -->
```

============== UPDATE =============

This is what is being returned when I run it.

```
insuranceSlideArray = .insuranceItem0,.insuranceItem1,.insuranceItem2,.insuranceItem3,.insuranceItem4,.insuranceItem5,.insuranceItem6,.insuranceItem7

insuranceSlideWidthArray = 420,560,700,280,280,700,700,280
```

My Problem comes when I need to actually USE the information that is being set in the array to make the container div slide left or right using the widths set in insuranceSlideWidthArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working code in case anyone was actually interested...

```
$('.insurance-slider-next').click(function(){
    insuranceNextSlide ++;
    if (insuranceCurrentSlide < insuranceTotalSlides) {
        slideNewWidth = insuranceSlideWidthArray[thisSlide];
        thisSlide ++;
        $('.insurance-slide-controller').animate({ 'left': '-=' + slideNewWidth + 'px' }, insuranceSlideSpeed );
        insuranceCurrentSlide = insuranceNextSlide;
    } else {
        resetInsuranceSlider();
        insuranceNextSlide = insuranceCurrentSlide;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an array of the insurance slider item widths and know which of them is in place so you know how much to slide left. You then simply update a variable which points to the current element in the array.

Take care with localised variables and don't forget that 70px is a bit of an oddity as a baseline.

Comment: I am already building a couple arrays, one for the widths and one with the slider items. My Problem comes when I need to utilize that information to set the VAR with the width of the current slide. I updated the OP with the array information that is being spit out in the console

Comment: You already have an index variable which you increment and decrement. Now simply apply it to the array in the form `s = a[i]`

Comment: Thanks Steve, please disregard my ignorance but I've never used arrays before this so I'm not sure how to do that. Maybe a practical example? I've been searching but can't seem to find something similar... Probably because I'm doing this all wrong to begin with haha

Comment: Actually, your comment " s = a[i] " was more helpful then the link... Just took me a little while to figure out how to plug that into my code. It's sort of working now, but for some reason it is starting at with the 3rd element in the array.

Comment: Possibly because you need a separate index starting at zero due to the asynchronous nature of your `each()`. Other than the `console.log`, does that `++` need to be in there?

Comment: 'slideNewWidth = insuranceSlideWidthArray[insuranceNextSlide-2];
    $('.insurance-slide-controller').animate({ 'left': '-=' + slideNewWidth + 'px' }, insuranceSlideSpeed );'

Comment: I added the ++ in there in order to add a class name to each slide which i can use to style specific slides easier if need be

Comment: I just used a seperate ++ for the paging and the logic works perfect now. Just need to restyle a little bit since that 70px you mentioned is being problematic now that the slides are not a set width anymore. Thanks a lot Steve you've been a big help, Much appreciated.